# When to use “dormir”, “endormir”, “rendormir”?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

I am curious about how to use the verbs *dormir*, *endormir* and *rendormir* - which one is appropriate in particular circumstances?  I also see that *me/te/se* can be used as well before *endormir*.  Just looking for some clarification.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

- ***Dormir*** is a static state: (to sleep, to be sleeping).
- ***(S')endormir*** is the transition between being awake and sleeping (to fall asleep/to put to sleep)
- ***(Se) rendormir*** is is the same as endormir but when happening after waking-up (to fall asleep again/to put to sleep again)

The last two verbs are usually pronominals.

Comment: "Fall asleep" cannot have a direct object, it cannot be used for *endormir*, you need a different verb in English.

Comment: @Laure Indeed, thanks. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

**Dormir** describes the action of going to sleep on purpose.
Like "Je vais aller dormir" for "I am going to sleep"

**Endormir** is more like "falling asleep", accidentally or against your will.
Like "Je me suis endormi sur mon bureau" for "I felt asleep on my desk".
Or "Ce prof est en train de m'endormir" for "This teacher is making me falling asleep".

**Rendormir** (Usually **se** rendormir) is used when you were asleep, woke up, and (on purpose or accidantally/against your will) go back to your sleep

**Endormi** is used to describe the state you're are asleep.
Like "Elle est endormie" for "She is asleep"

Comment: "Dormir" doesn't mean "to go to sleep" but just "to sleep". There is no "on purpose" vs "accidental/against your will" nuance between "endormir" en "dormir", just a chronological succession.

Comment: Je crois que vous voulez dire « i fell asleep » et pas « felt asleep »

Answer (score 0):

*me (m')/te/se* before *endormir* can indicate it is [reflexive verb](http://www.languagesonline.org.uk/French/Grammar/Reflexive/ReflexGram.htm).

French expresses the various meanings around *sleep* through prefixation of *dormir* or uses those derivatives as [reflexive verb](http://www.languagesonline.org.uk/French/Grammar/Reflexive/ReflexGram.htm), whereas in English, to convey the same meanings, we mostly use another verb along *sleep* or a phrasal verb.

**1**.  ***Dormir*** is sleep.

**2**. ***Endormir***
Prefix *en* indicates here a change of state<sup>1</sup>.  *Endormir* is `put to sleep`.

> *Ce genre de musique m'endort*<sup>1</sup>.

```
This type of music puts me to sleep/makes me sleep.
```

> *La maman endort le bébé en lui chantant une berceuse*.

```
 The mother sings the baby to sleep with a lullaby.
```

> *On fait une piqure au malade pour l'endormir*.

```
The patient receives an injection to put him to sleep.
```

**3**. ***S'endormir***, reflexive verb,  is something we do to ourselves, without outside intervention. `Fall asleep / go to sleep`

> *Je m'endors régulièrement à la tombée du jour*.

```
I regularly fall asleep/go to sleep when night falls.
```

**4.** ***Rendormir***
Prefix *re* indicates here the return to a previous state<sup>1</sup>.   `Verb + back to sleep`

> *L'infirmière fit une piqure au malade pour le rendormir*.

```
The nurse gave the patient an injection to put him back to sleep.
```

**5.** ***Se rendormir***, reflexive verb.

> *Je me réveille toujours vers cinq heures du matin mais je me rendors toujours*.

```
I always wake up around five but I always go back to sleep.
```

<sub>1. It has  several other  meanings.</sub>
<sub>2. *m'* is the object personal pronoun, it does **not** indicate here a reflexive verb.</sub>
<sub>3. re+endormir → rendormir: one *e*.</sub>